# Trace a specific value in an object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, trace

Data grid with information loaded via a CSV file. Users need to be able to filter the datagrid results via 2 combo boxes.

When I use

```
var objRow:Object;
var rowNumber:Number = codes_cb.selectedItem.data;  
objRow = myGrid.getItemAt(rowNumber);
```

It returns the row object which is fine. However
, I need to trace a specific cell value from that row. This works fine as a static trace:

```
trace(objRow.SelectAgreement);
```

"SelectAgreement" is the column header for one of the columns, But i need the "SelectAgreement" part to be dynamic.

Is there a variable type that can be used here? I've tried:

```
trace(objRow.codes_cb.selectedItem.label);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to properties of `Object`s in a similar way to how you refer to entries in an `Array`. EG:

```
var propName:String = "SelectAgreement";//the property to access
trace(objRow[propName]);//will trace the property value
```

So if you have a combo box with which lists these property names literally:

```
trace(objRow[comboBoxWithPropNames.selectedItem]);
```